# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment in dot product calculation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, dot-product

i have the dataframe as follow

```
    Tweet = data.columns.values[0]
    Rscore = data.columns.values[1]
    Nscore = data.columns.values[2]
    Label = data.columns.values[3]
```

the Rscore and Nscore values for each column should be drived from the dot similarty of two vectors as follow

```
for value in range(0,len(dataVector)):
    vector = dataVector[value]
    score = numpy.dot(vector,flattenNRumor[:50])
    Nscore[value] = score
```

but I got

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: The error is telling you *exactly* what the problem is. Idk what you think should happen but `Nscore` is a string, basically whatever the 3rd label of your column axis is. Then you do `Nscore[2]`, which is the character in the 2nd index location, and you try to set that to a value, which you just can't do because that's not how python works.

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to what each line of your code is doing.  You should **know**, not guess, what each variable is.

Assuming `data` is a `DataFrame`, then`data.columns` is the columns `Index`, and `data.columns.values` is an array with those column **names**.  `[2]` selects the 3rd **name**.

```
Nscore = data.columns.values[2]
```

`Nscore` is a string, a column name.  It is not a column, a `pandas.Series`, so it cannot be changed or take a numeric value.

Comment: i didn't guess, i was practising on some codes and  looked after a way to deal with the clolumns in pandas dataframe and this method should gave each colum a name so we can use it as a refrence in other places in the code

Comment: This method gives you the name of a column, but that isn't the same as the column itself.  Try `data[Nscore][value] = score`.